# how to find both symlinks and dirs using find command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I hate the find command, just want to get that out there. By far the worst designed CLI tool in linux land that I have used over many years.

Turns out, the following command will return nothing:

```
cd "$go_proj_path_root" && cd .. && find "$go_proj_path_root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -type d
```

it returns nothing because apparently -type l and -type d contradict each other? If I just use:

```
cd "$go_proj_path_root" && cd .. && find "$go_proj_path_root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

then it will find the symlinks in the dir. Is there some way to find both dirs and symlinks with the same command? Truly awful, find! If I just wanted symlinks, then I would just use `-type l`..wtf.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `-type l -type d` means "if the file is a directory *and* a symbolic link".  What you might want to try is `\( -type l -o -type d \)`.

Note too that your `cd` is not neccesary (unless you're using it to verify that `$go_proj_path_root` is a directory that you have access to):

```
find "$go_proj_path_root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -type l -o -type d \) -print
```

Alternatively, since you seem to only be interested in the files in a single directory:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
for name in "$go_proj_path_root"/*; do
    if [ -d "$name" ] || [ -L "$name" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

With the `zsh` shell:

```
print -rC1 -- $go_proj_path_root/*(ND/) $go_proj_path_root/*(ND@)
```

... where the glob qualifiers `/` and `@` will cause the preceding globbing pattern to only match directories or symbolic links respectively, and `ND` has the same effects as setting the `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options in `bash` (expand to nothing if no match and also match hidden names). The `print -rC1` will print the resulting names in a single column (`-r` avoids interpreting backslash sequences).

Comment: Since `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` are global parameters, there’s no need to protect the `-o` or use `-print` (but yes, it’s a good habit to get into).

Answer (score 1):

When you add criteria to find, it applies them all by default: so

```
find "$go_proj_path_root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -type d
```

is asking for files which are simultaneously links and directories.

You need to use “or”:

```
find "$go_proj_path_root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -o -type d
```

While it’s not necessary here, it’s a good idea to get into the habit of using parentheses around `-o`:

```
find "$go_proj_path_root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -type l -o -type d \)
```

(escaped so they don’t mean anything to the shell).

Comment: this prob works, and so does my answer? only tested mine once